# Откуда взялось слово "простофиля"?

Tags: этимология

"Дурачина ты, простофиля" — это помнят все. Но вот интересно, откуда вообще взялось слово "простофиля"? Просто — Филя?)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем-то, по всей видимости, всё действительно просто. Простофиля - это просто+Филя. А вот далее начинаются сложности. По каким причинам именно Филя, а не Иван или Пётр и прочие. Дело в том, что собственные имена, начинавшиеся когда-то чуждым восточному славянству звуком "ф", а также собственные имена, содержащие звук "х", чаще всего получали презрительное, бранное значение; ср. Фофан из Феофан, Фефёла— из Феофила, Фаля из Фалалей, Фетюк из Феотих и др.В говорах московской области имя Агафон стало нарицательным для глупцов: "Экай Агафон - все в рот тащит".  Далее я просто процитирую отрывок из сочинения Виноградова В. В. "История слов", так как у него это слово разбирается довольно подробно и обстоятельно.

> Собственное имя Филя вошло и в состав
> слова  простофиля .  Простофиля  —
> слово сложное (...) Первая часть слова
> простофиля  — просто- (или прост-о)
> невольно сопоставляется с аналогичным
> компонентом в словах: простолюдин,
> простонародье, простонародный,
> просторечие, простосердечие и др.
> под., с одной стороны, и с выражениями
> вроде гоголевского просто Фетюк в
> «Мертвых душах» — с другой.
> Характерно, что  простофиля  при
> ослабленной экспрессивности может
> стать в один и тот же синонимический
> ряд со словом простак. Вторая часть
> слова  простофиля  — Филя обычно
> истолковывается как собственное имя
> ласкательное от Филат или Филипп так
> же, как Фаля от Фалалей. Ср. также
> областн. Савоська из Севастьян в
> значении ` простофиля '. М.  И.
> Михельсон находил в простофиле
> отголоски Филатки— дурачка, простака
> Фили, но не отрицал возможности
> связывать это слово с Филей —
> простонародным названием червонного
> валета или с Памфилом— игрой в
> дурачки. Ни одна из этих
> этимологических гипотез не
> подтверждалась никакими фактами
> (Михельсон, Русск. мысль и речь, 1912,
> с. 710). А. Преображенский также
> считал этимологию слова  простофиля 
> неясной. «По всей вероятности, из
> просто- и собств. имени Филя, ласк. от
> Филат, Филипп; ср. у Даля (сл. 1909,
> 4, с. 1140 и след.) филя, филатка,
> дурачок, разиня» (Преображенский, 2,
> с. 134).
>
> Слово  простофиля  со значением
> «простак» внесено в «Словарь Академии
> Российской» (1822, ч. 5, с. 641). Там
> же помещено производное
> прилагательное: «Простофилеват, та,
> то, пр. простонар. То же что
> простоват, глуповат» (там же, с. 640).
>
> Филя, Филька в дворянском
> крепостническом обиходе XVII—XVIII вв.
> было типическим именем
> крестьянина-холопа, слуги. Это имя
> считалось простонародным и было
> окружено экспрессией пренебрежения,
> презрения. Д.  И. Фонвизин в письме к
> Козодавлеву о плане Российского
> словаря 1784 г. называет все
> пословицы, где есть Сенюшки и Фили, т.
> е. крестьянские пословицы, «весьма
> низкими и умом и выражением» и
> выражает пожелание, чтобы они все были
> поскорее забыты (см. Фонвизин 1830, ч.
> 4, с. 23). Ср. среди пословиц,
> приводимых И.  Н.  Болтиным в
> примечаниях на начертание для
> составления «Словесно-российского
> толкового словаря»: «У Фили пили, да
> Филю же и побили» (Сухомлинов, вып. 5,
> с. 281). В мемуарах и в художественной
> литературе XVIII — первой половины XIX
> в. Филька выступает как ярлык слуги.
> Так, у Б. И. Куракина в «Дневнике и
> путевых заметках 1705—1710 г.»:
> «Февраля 15 учился Филька оправлевать
> париков, дано 6 гульденов». (Русск.
> быт, ч. 1, с. 39).
>
> Из XVIII в. слово Филя как типическая
> кличка простоватого, глуповатого слуги
> переходит и в XIX в. Оно находит
> широкое применение в русской
> художественной литературе. Из анализа
> и сопоставления контекстов
> употребления этого слова следует с
> несомненностью, что Филя — это
> ласкательно-фамильярная форма к имени
> Филипп. Ср. в Череповецком говоре:
> «Фúльиха. Прозвище: от Филипп»
> (Герасимов. Сл. Череповецк. говора, с.
> 91).
>
> У Грибоедова в «Горе от ума» (в речи
> Фамусова):
>
> Ты, Филька, ты прямой чурбан,
>
> В швейцары произвел ленивую тетерю...
>
> (д.  4, явл.  14)
>
> В историческом романе О.  Ш.
> (Шишкиной) «Князь Скопин-Шуйский, или
> Россия в начале XVII столетия» (1835)
> также фигурирует слуга Филька:
> «”Ахти!” — вскричала Попадья, сама
> стряпавшая с работницами, ”пирог-то у
> нас не поспеет! Это все злодей Филька;
> велено принести рыбу живую, он и
> притащи ее к самой обедне! Ну, что,
> девки, станешь теперь делать?“» (ч. 1,
> гл. 4, с. 78). У И. И. Панаева в
> рассказе «Актеон» (1841): «У самого
> крыльца стояло человек до десяти
> исполинов, еще десять Антонов,
> которые, однако, назывались не
> Антонами, а Фильками, Фомками,
> Васьками, Федьками, Яшками и
> Дормидошками. Все они, впрочем, имели
> одно общее название малый» (1888, 2,
> с. 158). «Антон мигнул Фильке, и
> Филька побежал исполнить приказание
> барина» (там же, с. 171). «В грязной
> передней, где обыкновенно Филька шил
> сапоги, Дормидошка чистил медные
> подсвечники и самовар, Фомки, Федьки,
> Яшки и другие храпели и дремали, лежа
> и сидя на деревянных истертых и
> запачканных лавках, Петр Александрыч
> закричал: — Эй вы, сони! я всех
> разбужу вас...» (там же, с. 181). У
> него же в очерке «Барышня» (1844):
> «Евграф Матвеич колеблющимися шагами
> приблизился к гувернантке. — А вы
> куда? — спросила она его шопотом. —
> Я-с... я-с... я так здесь искал
> человека-с... Фильку...» (там же, с.
> 449). У того же Панаева в «Парижских
> увеселениях» (1846): «Гарсоны (не
> имеющие, впрочем, ничего общего с
> нашими Фильками и Васьками)...
> успевали удовлетворять требованиям
> каждого» (4, с. 256). В повести
> Панаева «Маменькин сынок» (1845):
> «Очнувшись, он с удивлением начал
> озираться кругом себя, протирая глаза.
> — Филька! Филька! — Чего изволите-с? —
> Да куда ж это мы едем? — К маменьке в
> деревню, сударь...» (там же, ч. 1, гл.
> 4, с. 371). В том же произведении:
> «”Ну что, Машка”, — спросила у нее
> барыня: ”говорила ты что-нибудь с
> Филькой?.. Чтó, доволен он своим
> барином?“» (там же, гл. 5, с. 375).
> Тут же раскрывается, что Филька — это
> уменьшительно-презрительное от Филипп:
> « — А не говорил ли Филька, привез ли
> барин с собою сколько-нибудь денег?..
> Осталось ли у него что-нибудь после
> того, как он заложил свое имение?.. —
> Какое, сударыня! Филипп Андреич
> рассказывает, что они все спустили в
> Москве до копеечки, что они так жили
> богато, что ужасти...» (там же, с.
> 376). Ср.: «Но после второго стакана
> вишневки Филька сделался как-то
> говорливее. Анна Трофимовна все
> продолжала его потчевать и притом
> глядела на него необыкновенно приятно
> и называла его ”Филипушкой“ и
> ”голубчиком“» (там же, ч. 2, гл. 2, с.
> 422).
>
> У В. И. Даля в повести «Павел
> Алексеевич Игривый»: «...даже сидевший
> за каретой на горе Монблане Филька
> снял дорожный картуз свой и низенько
> раскланивался» (Даль 1897, 1, с. 20).
> У Тургенева в рассказе «Собака»: «Я
> кликнул своего слугу; Филькой он у
> меня прозывается. Вошел слуга со
> свечкой. — Что это, — я говорю, —
> братец Филька, какие у тебя
> беспорядки! Ко мне собака под кровать
> затесалась» (7, с. 40). Точно так же в
> «Преступлении и наказании» Ф. М. 
> Достоевского Свидригайлов
> рассказывает: «Филька, человек
> дворовый у меня был; только что его
> похоронили, я крикнул, забывшись:
> ”Филька, трубку!“ — вошел, и прямо к
> горке, где стоят у меня трубки. Я
> сижу, думаю: ”Это он мне отомстить,
> потому что перед самою смертию мы
> крепко поссорились“» (ч. 4, гл. 1). А
> далее этот Филька называется — в
> передаче речи других лиц — Филиппом:
> «Вы, конечно, Авдотья Романовна,
> слышали тоже у них об истории с
> человеком Филиппом, умершим от
> истязаний, лет шесть назад, еще во
> время крепостного права» (ч. 4, гл.
> 2).
>
> Экспрессивно-бранное и презрительное
> значение дурачка, простачка слово Филя
> приобрело в устной народной речи не
> позднее XVIII в. В «Русском Жилблазе»:
> «Илья Лорнетов, этот глупый Филя,
> берет Энни» (Симоновский, Русский
> Жилблаз, ч. 2, с. 34).
> Разговорно-ироническое выражение —
> филькина грамота в значении:
> «невежественный;
> безграмотно-составленный документ» —
> восходит к тому же представлению о
> безграмотном и невежественном
> простаке-крестьянине, к представлению
> о глупом простаке Фильке. Любопытна
> такая реплика одного из персонажей
> романа Мельникова-Печерского «В
> лесах»: «Уж и объегорил же я его, обул
> как Филю в чертовы лапти!..
> Ха-ха-ха!.. Не забудет меня до веку».
>
> Параллельно с Филей распространяется и
> употребление
> простонародно-фамильярного слова — 
> простофиля .
>
> Ср. у Пушкина в «Сказке о рыбаке и
> рыбке»:
>
> Дурачина ты,  простофиля !
>
> Выпросил, дурачина, корыто!
>
> В корыте много ли корысти?
>
> .............................
>
> Дурачина ты, прямой  простофиля !
>
> Выпросил,  простофиля , избу!
>
> У Кс.  Полевого в «Записках о жизни и
> сочинениях Николая Алексеевича
> Полевого»: «Булгарин обратился ко мне
> так просто и радушно, как старый
> знакомый; он даже показался мне
> смиренным и кротким простофилей»
> (СПб., 1860, с. 273).

Answer (score 0):

Чуть-чуть упущено самое начало этого словотворчества: в XI - XII веках на Руси шла активная борьба меж несколькими церквями, среди которых были и "греки", ветвь, опирающаяся на Охрид, где службы велись на греческом языке, как у нынешних католиков-"латинян" на латыни. Тогда их противники ввели в разговорный язык много якобы греческих слов: ахинея, катавасия, куролесить (их правильное значение - мудрость, многоголосие, господи помилуй). Среди них было и слово фило = любовь. Чёрный пиар изобрели отнюдь не в сегодня.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).