# Почему простофиля прямой?

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов

Из «дурачины, прямого простофили» последнее понятие не нуждается в анализе, но вот второе... Почему «чурбан прямой», — так или иначе понятно.

Но ведь *Филя, Филька* ([Откуда взялось слово "простофиля"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/19362/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F)) уже и так простак, — тот, кто кажется всем понятен в своём устройстве и действует прямолинейно.

Answer (score 5):

[Здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9) со ссылкой на "Словарь русского языка" в 4-х т. говорится следующее:

> **Прямой**
>
> ...
>
> 5. ... || только полн. ф. Подлинный, настоящий, действительный. *Дурачина ты, прямой простофиля! Выпросил, простофиля, избу!* Пушкин, Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке.

**Почему «чурбан прямой» — так или иначе понятно.**

Да, по той же причине, видимо.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Жаль, что пример в статье тот же, из сказки.

Answer (score 2):

**ПРЯМОЙ**

В словаре [**Даля**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/342714/%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%AF%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%99):
Правый, истый, истинный, настоящий, самый он. Он прямой слуга царский и прямой христианин. Это прямая цена, без запросу. Прямой ты дурак. Прямой, что дурной, южн. (глупый). Кто друг прямой, тот брат родной.

В толковом словаре [**Ефремовой**](http://%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9):
7) *перен.* Полный, совершенный, явный.
9) *перен.* Подлинный, настоящий, неподдельный.

*Ты, Филька, ты прямой чурбан, // В швейцары произвел ленивую тетерю…*
А. Грибоедов

*Сын крепко рукою

Хватил себя в лоб

И думал с собою:

"**Прямой остолоп!**.."*
И. С. Никитин. [**Неудачная присуха**](http://libverse.ru/nikitin/neydachnaya-prisyha.html) (1854)

*На бумаге-то ты герой и разумник получился, а по жизни, извини уж, **прямой дурак.***
М. Успенский. Время Оно

**Дополнение**
Для полного понимания "почему простофиля прямой?" приведу ещё примеры:

***Прямой болван***, что пришел незван (Даль. Пословицы).

*Как рассердится на это старая колдунья да и кричит:

— Ах ты дура, **прямая дура**! Да, ведь, это волшебная епанча, а не что-нибудь другое, и ей следует быть в моих руках, а не у этого пустомели.*
Братья Гримм. [**Ослиный салат**](http://az.lib.ru/g/grimm/text_53_oslinyj_salat.shtml) (перевод С. Снессоревой, 1871)

Прямой дурак, прямая дура = полный дурак, полная дура;
прямой остолоп = настоящий остолоп;
прямой болван = истинный болван;
прямой простофиля = явный, действительный простофиля.

Comment: Спасибо. Поскольку вывода нет, подытожу своими словами: потому как — наследник по прямой линии.

Comment: Вы хотели меня обидеть? У @grizzly нет ни выводов, ни примеров (кроме собственно Вашего примера - в вопросе), но в его сторону Вы шпильки не отпускаете. Извините, но мне казалось, что вывод напрашивается сам собой - для участника с многолетним опытом.

Comment: Нисколько. И что нет прямого ответа (или просмотрел?) меня, без шуток, устраивает, и не только меня, судя по плюсикам. Спасибо — натуральное, без издёвки и шпилек. Вывод сделал по итогам своего и вашего с grizzly размышлений: прямой простофиля потому, что сын простофили.